# Why my button is not calling my function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to call a function to change the contents of a `<p>` tag, it appears that my function is not being called, thanks in advance.

I've checked that all the tags have `runat="server"`, and making sure the function name is correct.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace StepFollowingDemo
{
    public partial class Test1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            void Yeah()
            {
                string Some = Something.Value;
                this.Result.InnerHtml = Some;
            }
       }

    }
}

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test1.aspx.cs" Inherits="StepFollowingDemo.Test1" %>
```

## Test Case

```
<label runat="server" for="Something">Type:</label>
<input runat="server" type="Text" class="from-control" id="Something"/>
<button runat="server" type="button" onclick="Yeah();" class="btn btn-success">Project your words</button>
<br /><br />

<label runat="server" for="Result">Output: </label>
<p runat="server" id="Result"></p>
```

Comment: Maybe some tutorials first? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/introduction-and-overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to run that code server-side. I see two problems:

1. You will need to use an [ASP Button control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button?view=netframework-4.8), like `<asp:Button>`. Look at that documentation for details about how to use it. The `<button>` tag is not an ASP control, so that `onclick` is running client-side. It is looking for a javascript function.
2. You declared that method inside `Page_Load` and with the wrong signature for an event. Move it out of `Page_Load`, under the class:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void Yeah(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string Some = Something.Value;
    this.Result.InnerHtml = Some;
}
```

Also, `Yeah` isn't the usual naming convention, but it would still work.